# ConcurrentModificationException when accessing Executor Service Future List

Tags: java, collections, concurrentmodification

I am trying to make parallel requests using executor service. After it is complete, I am accessing the Future using below code in Java 7. All I am trying is to store it in a new List called `infos`. I see `ConcurrentModificationException` exception. Any advice on how to get rid of it ?

```
        List<Info> infos = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Future<Info> fut : list){
            try {
                infos.add(fut.get()); // ConcurrentModificationException happening here...
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // send infos
```

Update -

```
private List<Future<Info>> list;

    Future<Info> future = executor.submit(callable);
    list.add(future);
```

Comment: What is `list`? Are you *sure* the `ConcurrentModificationException` happens in that line of code? Neither `add(...)` nor `get()` throws that exception. The `for` loop itself *could*, if `list` is modified by a different thread while the loop is running, depending on that `list` is.

Comment: I am adding all Future to the list. So we need to change the for loop to iterator ?

Comment: The `for` loop *is* an `Iterator` loop. That's why *it* can throw the exception, given that iterators and sublists are just about the only causes of that particular exception.

Comment: Perhaps, you’re confused because `Future.get` throws an `ExecutionException` wrapping an exception that happened within the background task?

Answer (score 1):

Your list is of type `Future<Infos>` while in enhanced for loop, you are using Info.

```
 for(Future<Info> fut : list)
```

Your code should be:

```
    private List<Future<Info>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Future<Info> future = executor.submit(callable);
    list.add(future);
```

Comment: true, I made a mistake while changing the type of it. now I have corrected it. but that is not the issue.